# vector<vector<int>> takes too long initialize

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have some codes written in c++, it is a simple program to find out pair-wise dmin for a graph which has 3000+ vertices. All edges have the same weight 1. So I do BFS over all pairs of vertices.

My program runs not fast enough, so I did a profiling on my codes using Xcode 4.2.1's product->profile. 
It calls a tool called "instruments". After a while, I figured out how to use it. But what I got is very confusing. How could the highlighted line use so much time? Any thought is highly appreciated.

I defined:
vector visited;
vector< vector > G;//adjacency list
[image]

Comment: Does it finish? It could be an infinite loop?

Comment: You have 3000+ vertices. Out of curiosity, how many edges?

Comment: @ColeJohnson, yes, it finishes.

Comment: @WhozCraig, it is a sparse graph, so number of edges is roughly 3 times number of vertices.

Comment: Have a look at the boost graph library. In particular they have a compressed sparse row graph data structure that will give you much better performance than a vector of vectors.

Comment: Major thing: mark things as visited when you add them to queue, not when you take them out. Minor thing: you can factor `std::vector<int>& vertex = G[n]` out of the for loop.

Comment: @zch, thanks for your suggestion! You are right, i should mark at insertion. Factoring G[n] out should speed up the program too.

Comment: Don't post an image of the code. Post the code!

Comment: Factoring G[n] out of the loop can be probably done by the compiler. But worth a try, anyway. However, the algorithm's time complexity looks O(n^2).

Comment: Another point to consider is, Instruments may not *exactly* locate the source line when the compiler has optimized the code. The whole or major part of the inner loop could be the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

The instruments run is telling you that the vast majority of the time visited[G[n][i]] is true.

Comment: I didn't realize instruments counts in this way... Now this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of time taken in the statement: `(visited[G[n][i]] == false)` would be due to massive cache misses.

Note that `G` is a big 3k*3k matrix, taking a contiguous virtual memory space, and `visited` is another 3k array taking *another* contiguous memory at a different location in the virtual memory space. Accessing both the memory locations in the same statement will cause lots of cache misses depending on the capacity of your processor's cache.

To gain a speed-up, rewrite the program keeping in mind [locality of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference).

Comment: Good point, that makes sense. Can you give some example on how I can make (visited[G[n][i]] == false) to follow locality of reference?

Comment: @user2883918, as you already mentioned in your earlier comment that you are considering factoring G[n] out of the loop. This will help a little bit depending upon your machine. For smaller machines, major advantage is gained when "visited" is clubbed together with "G". That is, when G is represented as a vector of all nodes, where each node has an adjacency list as well as a boolean "visited" variable.

Comment: If you've got multidimensional arrays and are suffering from cache problems then try swapping in [boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) which also lets you customise the order in which the dimensions are stored, so you can experiment to get the best performance.